# What is the latest version of structuremap that supports .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, structuremap

I'm working on a project that is stuck on .NET 2.0 (though we can use C# 3.0), and I'd like to use the facilities of a nice container (e.g. StructureMap).  Does anyone know what the latest version of StructureMap that supports .NET 2.0 is?

Or if there is any other container (preferably not Unity, but I could be convinced) that supports .NET 2.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [StructureMap-2.0](https://github.com/downloads/structuremap/structuremap/StructureMap-2.0.zip). The next release which is [StructureMap.2.4.9](https://github.com/downloads/structuremap/structuremap/StructureMap.2.4.9.zip) already depends on the `System.Core` assembly which is .NET 3.5.