# What is the latest version of StructureMap that supports .Net 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, structuremap

I would like to use the newest version, but can't use anything dependent on .Net 4.0 or newer for a new project.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008346/what-is-the-latest-version-of-structuremap-that-supports-net-2-0), so I know I can at least use version 2.4.9, but can I use any newer version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a .Net 3.5 project I work on, I use structuremap 2.6.3. I added the reference with NuGet. Version 2.6.4 and 2.6.4.1 was not possible to install thru NuGet on a 3.5 project, but 2.6.3 was.

```
install-package structuremap -Version 2.6.3
```